# Add Lazy Loading in Data-Table at both vertical sides

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I created lightning-datatable lwc component with lazy-loading data, if user scrolling bottom. But I have not idea, how to read scroll position property lightning-datatable element, if user scroll to top, for realize lazy-loading in both horizontal sides.
Html sample:

`<div style='height: 400px' if:true={columnsReady}>
            <lightning-datatable data={accounts}
                                 columns={columns}
                                 key-field="Id"
                                 enable-infinite-loading
                                 onloadmore={loadMoreData}
            >
            </lightning-datatable>
        </div>`

JS:

```
 @api fieldSet;
@track accounts;
columns;
@track columnsReady = false;

loadMoreData(event) {
    event.target.isLoading = true;
    getMoreAccounts({account: this.accounts[this.accounts.length - 1]})
        .then((data) => {
            this.accounts = this.accounts.concat(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert('Failed load rows. Error - ' + error);
        });
    event.target.isLoading = false;
}

connectedCallback() {
    getColumns({fs: this.fieldSet})
        .then((data) => {
            this.columns = JSON.parse(data);
            this.columnsReady = true;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert('Failed load columns. Error - ' + error);
        });
    getAccounts({fieldSet: this.fieldSet})
        .then((data) => {
            this.accounts = data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert('Failed load start rows. Error - ' + error);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infinite Scrolling only works in the downward direction. It is intended that a developer will never remove the original rows of content while scrolling down. There's no way to read the internals of the lightning:datatable to figure out when the user has returned to the top of the table, as far as I can tell. If you need this feature, you'll have to write your own custom data table component.